# Rotating images based on CSS nth-child

Tags: javascript, css, dom, dom-manipulation, css-transitions

I was able to write a JavaScript carousel and thought it might be more compact to use CSS transitions with `nth-child` selectors like this:

```
img {
    transition: all 1s linear; /* or corresponding vendor prefixes */
    position:absolute;
}

img:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
}

img:nth-child(2) {
    top: 0%;
    left: 50%;
}

/*and so on...*/
```

The items would then be rotated by appending the first child or prepending the last child of the container:

```
parent.appendChild(parent.children[0]);
```

This approach works well for all but the appended element. It is removed entirely and then reattached, so it ends up in the right spot but *does not use the transition effect*. Is there a way to use CSS transitions even when relocating an element in the DOM?

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xqw2Q/1/) - Click the document to advance the images.

Comment: I'm not confident enough to answer but I really don't think so. CSS transitions operate on a plane above and independent of the organization of DOM elements. You could animate the append with Javascript or, better, switch to classes (box-1, box-2, box-3, box-4) instead of nth-child and use Javascript to increment each class on click or reset to 1 if previously on 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a `data-*` attribute and selector.  It is a little more verbose than `nth-child`, but has the advantage of working.  It is also cleaner than parsing through class lists.

Each element has a `data-order` attribute, which can be assigned with HTML or JavaScript:

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/203/203" data-order=0 />
```

Replace `nth-child` with the attribute selector:

```
img[data-order="1"] {
    top: 0%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

When rotating, increment the order in the [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dataset).  This seems to update the attribute, even though we are modifying the property:

```
var forEach = [].forEach,
    nodes = document.body.children,
    length = nodes.length;

//On rotate:
forEach.call(nodes, function(node) {
    node.dataset.order++;
    node.dataset.order %= length;
});
```

Here is the [final result](http://jsfiddle.net/Xqw2Q/7/).

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is you can add or remove a class name from an element. Example you have a `div` element. And its class value is `class="item"`. If you add another class name which has animation to that element's class name list, then that `div` element will show that animation at that moment immediately.

eg. `div.className += " animatedClass";`

Answer (score 1):

A very interesting issue indeed. And here is the solution I came up with. Adds some markup and some CSS, but accomplishes it while still using `nth-child`. Honestly, I may work on this some more later and see if I can't come up with a more elegant solution, but for now, I forked off a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RRpDe/).

The core of it is switching a class on a wrapper div, and using that to rotate through the styles.

However, as far as your actual question of can you animate an append image, you can, but not in the way you're thinking here. It would be an initial append animation, which would mean when the page first loaded it will animate. You can do this using [@keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@keyframes), and set it so that the image you want slides into place from a starting position of where it would be. But, again, this will happen on first load as well. You can fake it by 'spinning into place' for the first load. So, have all images spin once on load.